# Unused South African Visitor VISA

Tags: visas, south-africa

I am planning to apply for a 1 year multiple entry SA Visa. I have been to SA twice for a month each time, but this time it's a longer one with multiple entries.

The purpose of my visit would be Visitor Visa - business meetings category but I wounder what happens if I apply for a SA visa for an year and don't use it even once? Are their any implications? Will the embassy decline my VISA request afterwards? Any drawbacks?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, many visas go unused. People's plans and lives change all the time, not everything in life always goes to plan.